# Error with operands when making a counter

Tags: vhdl

I was trying to make a counter which count up and then returns a value. However I have come across some errors and I am absolutely clueless as to how to fix them. I tried changing it to an integer but similar errors kept showing up (I am new so I might have screwed up). Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks Allen.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity counter is
    Port (Reset      : in   STD_LOGIC;
            Clock      : in   STD_LOGIC;
            CountEvent : in   STD_LOGIC;
            GC         : out  STD_LOGIC;
            AC         : out  STD_LOGIC;
            WC         : out  STD_LOGIC
              );
end counter;


architecture Behavioral of counter is
signal count : STD_LOGIC;

begin
     sync:
     process (Reset, Clock, CountReset)
     begin 
     count <= '0';
            if (Reset = '1') or (CountEvent = '1') then
                count <= '0';
            elsif (rising_edge(Clock)) then
                count <= count + 1;
            end if;
     end process sync;

     GC <= '1' when (count = 500) else '0';
     AC <= '1' when (count = 300) else '0';
     WC <= '1' when (count = 500) else '0';
end Behavioral;
```

the errors being shown are. For reference line 33 is 'end behavioral'.

ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "C:/.Xilinx/WEIEFN/count_final.vhd" Line 26. + can not have such operands in this context.
ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "C:/.Xilinx/WEIEFN/count_final.vhd" Line 30. = can not have such operands in this context.
ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "C:/.Xilinx/WEIEFN/count_final.vhd" Line 31. = can not have such operands in this context.
ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "C:/.Xilinx/WEIEFN/count_final.vhd" Line 32. = can not have such operands in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `count` is a `std_logic`, which is a single bit. No standard arithmetic operators exist in the `std_logic_1164` library for `std_logic` or `std_logic_vector` as they are not intended as types with a numerical representation.

To allow easy rollover and appropriate sizing, I recommend using the package `numeric_std` from the `ieee` library and making `count` an `unsigned` type. This is an array of `std_logic` that has arithmetic functions defined, treating the array as an unsigned value.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question how should I write count as an unsigned. I tried 'signal count : unsigned STD_LOGIC' but that doesn't look right.

Comment: `unsigned` is an array type, so you need to constrain the array bounds. `signal count : unsigned(9 downto 0);` will give you a 10 bit counter